# Unable to Install Magento 2.3 Via Composer

Tags: installation, magento2.3

I have php7.2 and composer installed via apt-get

When I try to install Magento 2.3 via composer...
composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/projec
t-community-edition

I have this issue:

our requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1

```
    - magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.0.3 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 requires magento/inventory-composer-metapackage ^1.0.3 -> satisfiable
 by magento/inventory-composer-metapackage[1.0.3].
    - magento/inventory-composer-metapackage 1.0.3 requires magento/inventory-composer-installer ^1.0.3 -> satisfia
ble by magento/inventory-composer-installer[1.0.3].
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-
edition[2.3.0].
```

> Potential causes:

- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
     see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251838/magento-2-2-6-to-2-3-upgrade-fails-with-composer

Comment: Ok, issue was on composer version, I updated it and now it's all Okay, Thanks @RaulSanchez

Comment: Same with me it's just the composer version. I updated it to the latest one and now the magento 2 upgrade is moving. Thanks