# How to upgrade magento 2.3.1 CE to 2.3.3 CE?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, magento-upgrade, command, magento2.3.3

I have magento 2.3.1 CE. I want to upgrade 2.3.1 to 2.3.3 CE with commands only. Does anyone know how to upgrade it with commands ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can follow this link https://blog.magestore.com/upgrade-magento-2-3/#a3

Comment: I tried it already. But not getting result. @PradipGarchar

Answer (score 2):

You can update your magento version using following command

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.3 --no-update
```

and then

```
composer update
```

after composer update finished run `setup:upgrade`

Ref: [Dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html)

Answer (score 1):

For Upgrade Magento 2.3.1 to 2.3.3 please follow all below steps.

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.3 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Follow all steps,if you face any issue let me know for the same.

Comment: It gives error when run "composer update" command. Any solution for that ? @Sangeeta

Comment: what error is showing, pls share screenshot..?

Comment: https://nimb.ws/cCNrYQ

Comment: @ChiragParmar : this link will help you for related to composer update error
 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252156/migrate-magento-1-9-2-1-to-magento-2-3-0


https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251838/magento-2-2-6-to-2-3-upgrade-fails-with-composer

Comment: first you need to upgrade composer in your system then run your command.

Comment: @ChiragParmar: your issue is solve or not yet....?

Comment: No. Already tried your given both links. Facing same error!

Comment: did you update composer at your system..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100033/discussion-between-chirag-parmar-and-sangeeta-chandaliya).

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this steps

```
- php bin/magento maintenance:enable
- cp composer.json composer.json.bak
- composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com magento/project-community-edition=2.3.3 temp_dir --no-install
- rm -rf update
- mv temp_dir/update .
- rm -rf temp_dir
- composer update
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- rm -rf var/cache/*
- rm -rf var/page_cache/*
- rm -rf generated/code/*
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento maintenance:disable
- service varnish restart
```

Ref : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Comment: I got error while on step composer update so i wrote like this : $composer update  --no-plugins.Still gives error :- Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.0.3 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.

Comment: what error you're getting, can you please share that ?

Comment: Here whole error is not able to write. I posted some lines of starting in previous comment. Now I am posting last line 
Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting  see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Comment: Do you have any third party extensions installed via composer ?

Comment: no. Its fresh M231 installation.

Comment: I think you're getting same issue like this one.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252156/migrate-magento-1-9-2-1-to-magento-2-3-0

Can you please check this solution work for you or not ?

Comment: I think your composer version is old which you're using and that is not matching with minimum stability. you need to first update your composer version.

can you please check which composer version you're using ?

composer --version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99951/discussion-between-chirag-parmar-and-kishan-savaliya).

Comment: @ChiragParmar, are you able to find any solution here ?

Comment: No. I did not find any proper solution. @Kishan Savaliya