# Appear error when upgrade from magento 2.3.2 to 2.3.3

Tags: layout, theme, magento-upgrade, magento2.3.3

### When we execute command line upgrade done appear error in the log:

- Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
- Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
- Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
- Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' element cannot be added as child to 'product.info.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
- Broken reference: the 'footer_blog_link' element cannot be added as child to 'footer_links', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
- Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
- Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []

  ### - Broken reference: the 'yotpo_bottomline' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addto', but their parents are different: 'product.info.main' and '' respectively. [] []

This is error via the screenshot: 
http://prntscr.com/pntyo3
[image]
Backend admin still working normal, only frontend not working (don't showing anything only show white page).*emphasized text*
Anyone can help me.
Thank you so much!

Comment: you can follow this steps. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292779/how-to-upgrade-magento-2-3-1-ce-to-2-3-3-ce

Comment: This issue was existing before during upgrading to Magento 2.2 also. This temporary fix solved it. Please checkout this https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/452#issuecomment-419663688

Comment: Thank for your support. I try again but still appear error as begining, don't any update. What happens?